# How to include the interface in the definition file generate by VS2012 for typesctipt

Tags: typescript

We create a type script project in VS2012, and define a interface of the typescript. Then we add implement of the interface and some business logic to use the interface. In the VS we compile the project into a definition file for the typescript. And there is a compile error in the description file, we check the error and fine the interface is not included in the description file of the project.

Our question:
**Is there way to include the interface into the description file for the TypeScript when we compile multiple TypeScript file into one file?**

Comment: "In the VS we compile the project into a definition file for the typescript" Why are you compiling a definition file? Definition files typically remain in TypeScript, they aren't compiled to JS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your question I am making the following assumptions.

- You are compiling your TypeScript using the `--out` flag to get a single output file
- You are generating definitions using the `--declaration` flag
- You have an interface in one file and an implementation in another file

If this is the case, your interface should appear in the declaration file. Here is an example.

## Example Code

InterfaceFile.ts

```
// Interface
interface IPoint {
    getDist(): number;
}
```

ImplementationFile.ts

```
/// <reference path="InterfaceFile.ts" />

// Module
module Shapes {

    // Class
    export class Point implements IPoint {
        // Constructor
        constructor (public x: number, public y: number) { }

        // Instance member
        getDist() { return Math.sqrt(this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y); }

        // Static member
        static origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

app.ts

```
/// <reference path="ImplementationFile.ts" />

// Local variables
var p: IPoint = new Shapes.Point(3, 4);
var dist = p.getDist();
```

## Compilation and Output

If I compile this example program with the following command:

```
tsc --out mylib.js --declaration app.ts
```

I get the following in mylib.d.ts

```
interface IPoint {
    getDist(): number;
}
module Shapes {
    class Point implements IPoint {
        public x: number;
        public y: number;
        constructor(x: number, y: number);
        public getDist(): number;
        static origin: Point;
    }
}
var p: IPoint;
var dist: number;
```

Comment: I find the issue I have, and make it works. We do some test for developing with TypeScript, such as use multiple projects to manage the typescript. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `.ts` instead of a `.d.ts` for your interface declaration files also.

You can see a sample here : https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/tree/master/tests/compileToSingle

My ***out.d.ts*** https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/blob/master/tests/compileToSingle/out.d.ts  contains the interface from dec***.ts***: https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/blob/master/tests/compileToSingle/dec.ts

My ***out.d.ts*** did not contain the interface : https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/blob/34eeb54618e57765ea0e2f9ce0c48ebd7f46942a/tests/compileToSingle/out.d.ts 
If I had a dec.***d.ts*** : https://github.com/basarat/ts-test/blob/34eeb54618e57765ea0e2f9ce0c48ebd7f46942a/tests/compileToSingle/dec.d.ts

You can use the declare keyword for any items that are only declarations i.e.:

```
declare class C{

}
```

instead of

```
class C{

}
```

Interfaces will stay the way they are and do not use the declare keyword for those.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you have both `<TypeScriptOutFile>something.js</TypeScriptOutFile>` and `<TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>true</TypeScriptGeneratesDeclarations>` defined in your csproj file.  As of TypeScript version 0.8.3.1 for me (and I assume 0.9) any interfaces referenced from an included file (and not in a .d.ts file) will also be included.  Just add a reference to the missing interface in one of your files and recompile.  The reference doesn't have to actually be used in that file.